# Can there be two primary key with auto increment for both?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a table which contains two primary key id.

Let me tell a little bit about my ideas to create this kind of table. Assume that there are 2 tables which contains all the same attributes but just different id. So, I planned to merge it so that it will not look too large. But the problem is i need for both id can be auto increment.

For example:

**Table A**

ID | Age | House | Source

**Table B**

ID | Age | House | Source

So, like i said i planned to merge both something like this:

**Table A&B**

ID_A | ID_B | Age | House | Source

There will be an input forms for both A & B. The thing is i need an auto increment for both ID. I'm not sure whether this can be done or not. I hope someone can explain to me.

Comment: What database are you using? All tags aren't relevant.

Comment: Why do you need two ID values?

Comment: no and no, i can think of multiple alternatives, but it depends on your specific need, you could create a new primary key in the new table and use that (store old key a and b if you nedd to), you could make a new primary key by combing a and b key, but you won't obe able to autoincrement it. pick one as the new primay key and use a trigger to update the other ...

Comment: Like highlander, there can be only one

Comment: @AbanaClara I'm using mysql

Comment: @Nick Because both of them is different from each other. I need both of the ID start auto incrementing

Comment: @ZulMajdi but what is the point of having two? What value does that add over having one?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/primary  The question I have is why you would have two identical tables with different data in the first place. I would presume that table A and table B indicate a different source?  Then use `source` for that purpose!

Comment: @tim Seems like my way can't be done. I don't know how to explain to my client as they urge me to make table looks like that. They want both id starting from 0

Comment: @TimMorton No the source is just a regular data. Because the main point from my problem is i want both id can be auto increment in the same table

Comment: What you are apparently dealing with is a bad case of technical debt. Having two tables with exactly the same fields but holding different data is horribly incompetent. If you’re tasked with straightening out this mess, you have to combine the data of both tables without duplicating a primary id of either. What you haven’t said is if there are any other tables that are related via A.id or B.id   If there are, you’ll have to rebuild the relationships.

Comment: Why was some data put in table A, but other data put in table B?  What is (or was) the determining factor for the destination?

Answer (score -1):

@Zul Majdi

That's not possible actually ,
But there is 2 way to achieve your requirement.

1) Create Sequence with start from 0.

2) Create trigger on table Oninsert and use that sequence to insert data into those column or within query you can use

```
        INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES(seq.nextval,?)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Zul Majdi is there anything worng in above ans ?

Comment: probably was a drive-by down vote. Your answer looks like it answers the question, but doesn’t deal with the fundamental misunderstanding the op and the customer have.

Comment: Yeah, it's like being slapped in the face for trying to help.